# Motor driver powered by PSU instead of battery

Tags: power-supply, battery-operated, motordriver

I am about to use a motor driver in a project (MDDS30 by Cytron) and I was going to power it using a 12v 11.5a PSU. I discovered that the manufacturer warns against using a PSU, and that it might destroy the driver if the motor is driven via an external force, as it would generate electricity that can kill the driver if it builds up and is not able to go in to a battery of some sort. I was considering having to use a lead acid accumulator in parallel with the PSU (I don't know if this is particularly safe or possible without adding circuitry?), but that is not ideal for several reasons in this application, mainly that the system should die if one unplugs the PSU...

So my question is this: Can I simply connect some large capacitor in parallel with the PSU instead of using a battery? And if that is so, what capacity and voltage rating should I opt for? it is not very likely that the motor would be rotated by hand, but I do not like to gamble on it being the case!

Perhaps any other solution I have not considered?
We have too little time to consider a different, less particular, driver at this point.

Thanks for any input

To update the question with some more information: The drivers operating range is 7-35V, my system is purely 12V, and other components includes a PLC. If a higher voltage than 12v is fed back into the system from the motors (like commenter glen_geek mentions) it might cause the PLC to become unstable.

Comment: The manufacturer is likely concerned about *over-voltage* killing the driver. A battery's voltage limits the overvolt by charging. A capacitor will charge through an overvoltage without limit - the driver will likely be destroyed before the capacitor breaks down. And most PSU's suffer the same problem when faced with an over-voltage.

Comment: You may want some sort of high-current "shunt regulator" likely of an active sort, ie, one where some type of semiconductor connects a power resistor to absorb the regenerated power.

Comment: Ok, looks like I found a product that does exactly what Chris Stratton suggests, a shunt regulator that kicks in at 13.2v, and absorbes the excess electricity, seems to be developed for this type of scenario. Here is a link to the regulators i found, the item description has a very good explanation of its purpose and use cases: https://www.pololu.com/category/249/shunt-regulators

Comment: That is the right idea, indeed, and I happened upon that link on the path towards the comment I made.  But those parts are seemingly an order of magnitude too small.